# Idiomatic service initialization/helpers in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I'm integrating Twilio (or any third party api) into a Rails project. I've got the gem loaded by bundler in my Gemfile and I've setup `config/twilio.yml` to store my api keys.

To instantiate a new Twilio client I'll have to parse that YAML file and load up whatever the config is for the current `Rails.env`. To mitigate parsing that file each time I've just pushed the config onto `MyApp::Application.config.twilio` in `config/initializers/twilio.rb`

Now when I need a Twilio client I'm faced with the verbose: `client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(MyApp::Application.config.twilio['sid'], MyApp::Application.config.twilio['auth'])`

I'd like to wrap that up in a helper somewhere so it's easily accessible from different parts of the system. Is there an idiomatic place to define that helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
class MyApp::Application
  def self.twilio_client
    Twilio::REST::Client.new(config.twilio['sid'], config.twilio['auth'])
  end
end
```

I usually define stuff like that in `lib/my_company/twilio_integration.rb`, which defines everything needed for the 3rd party integration, including `MyCompany::TwilioIntegration.client`.

Perhaps a better location would be in `app/models/twilio_integration.rb`, which could define `TwilioIntegration.client`